Clarification on SPONSORED_INMAILS and InMailContents API Deprecation in v202410
I would like to confirm some details regarding version 202410. Specifically, I noticed that the InMailContents API is marked for deprecation in the near future.
I am assuming that the SPONSORED_INMAILS ad type falls under the Message Ads API, which relies on the InMailContents API. This leads me to believe that the SPONSORED_INMAILS ad type may also be deprecated.
If that’s the case, will users no longer be able to create SPONSORED_INMAILS ad types on LinkedIn's UI dashboard? If yes, is there a specific date when this restriction will take effect?
Any insights or official references would be greatly appreciated.
I need Clarification on SPONSORED_INMAILS and InMailContents API Deprecation
